# PHP soapClient multiple calls fail

Tags: php, soap, mysqli, soap-client

I have to call a web service inside a while loop to submit several records from a database.
The problem is that only the first record is postet.
Seems that the webservice call makes terminate the while loop and the other records are not fetched anymore.
The webservice call itself is correct.
Someone can help me please ?

**Here is the code :**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
include("include/dbConn.php");

$client = new SoapClient("myservice.asmx?wsdl",array(
                        'exceptions'=>true,
                        'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                        'features' =>SOAP_WAIT_ONE_WAY_CALLS,
                        'encoding'=>'utf-8'));

$Context =array(
        "B1DBName" => "TestDB",
        "B1DefaultPriceListNumber" => "1",
        "B1UKStandardVatCode" => "O1",
);


$strSql="select * from custom_clients_insert_view";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$strSql) or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($conn) . "<hr>\nQuery: $strSql");  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $Cust =array(
        "CardCode" => "",
        "WebPassword" => "",
        "EmailAddress" => $row['email'],
        "Title" => "",
        "FirstName" => $row['b_firstname'],
        "Surname" => $row['b_lastname'],
        "Telephone" => $row['b_phone'],
        "WebID" => $row['user_id'],
        "VATNumber" => "",
        "FaxNumber" => $row['fax'],
        "Telephone2" => "",
        "Organisation" => "",
        "MobilePhone" => ""
    );

    $params = array(
    'Context' => $Context,
    'WebsiteName' => "test2",
    'Cust' => $Cust,
    'ActiveCust' => true
    );

    try 
    {
        $result = $client->SubmitNewCustomerToB1($params);
        var_dump($result);
        echo "<br><br> VALUE:" . $result->SubmitNewCustomerToB1Result;
        /* do something on my log */
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        echo "Error!<br />";
        echo $e -> getMessage ();
        var_dump($result);
        echo "<br><br> VALUE:" . $result->SubmitNewCustomerToB1Result;
        /* do something on my log*/
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to push the recordset in an array and then loop on the array using a for each statement.

Here is the working code:

```
include("include/dbConn.php");

$CustArray = array();

$client = new SoapClient("WSDL EDNPOINT HERE",array(
                        'exceptions'=>true,
                        'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                        'encoding'=>'utf-8'));

$strSql="SELECT * FROM custom_clients_insert_view";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$strSql) or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($conn) . "<hr>\nQuery: $strSql");  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{

    $Context =array(
        "B1DBName" => "TESTDB",
        "B1DefaultPriceListNumber" => "1",
        "B1UKStandardVatCode" => "O1",
    );


    $WebsiteName =array(
        "WebsiteName"=> "Test webiste"
    );

    $ActiveCust =array(
            "ActiveCust" => "true"
    );


    $Cust =array(
        "CardCode" => "",
        "WebPassword" => "",
        "EmailAddress" => $row['email'],
        "Title" => "",
        "FirstName" => $row['b_firstname'],
        "Surname" => $row['b_lastname'],
        "Telephone" => $row['b_phone'],
        "WebID" => $row['user_id'],
        "VATNumber" => "",
        "FaxNumber" => $row['fax'],
        "Telephone2" => "",
        "Organisation" => "",
        "MobilePhone" => ""
    );

    $params = array(
    'Context' => $Context,
    'WebsiteName' => $WebsiteName,
    'Cust' => $Cust,
    'ActiveCust' => $ActiveCust
    );

    array_push($CustArray, $params);
}

foreach ($CustArray as $params) 
{
    try 
    {
        $result = $client->SubmitNewCustomerToB1($params);
        var_dump($result);
        echo "<br><br> VALUE:" . $result->SubmitNewCustomerToB1Result;
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        echo "Error!<br />";
        echo $e -> getMessage ();
        var_dump($result);
        echo "<br><br> VALUE:" . $result->SubmitNewCustomerToB1Result;
    }
}
```